# QGIS - About Ignore Getmap/Gettile URI reported in capabilities

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, wms, wmts, getmap

Some WMS are working after checking the 1st option below. Can you suggest a resource or someone with knowledge of what exactly this option changes and how it makes WMS work?

[image: WMS/WMTS options in QGIS]

Comment: Be aware that clicking this by default may cause the service to fail, you should only use it if the service has been misconfigured, for example GetCapabilities returns local server name for a public service.

Answer (score 1):

The first communication with WMS server is done with GetCapabilities. The URL is for example

https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

GetCapabilities includes OnlineResources for other WMS requests. In this example the OnlineResource for GetMap is

```
<GetMap>
...
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wms?"/>
...
```

The base URL of GetMap, GetFeatureInfo etc. can be anything and it does not need to be the same than the base URL of GetCapabilities. One reason for using different GetMap URL is to share the load of the service for several servers. But very often the different base URL for GetMap is because of misconfigured server, and actually WMS clients should use the same base URL for all WMS requests.

The Ignore GetMap URI setting makes QGIS to use the GetCapabilities URL for all request instead of the OnlineResource URLs that appeat in the GetCapablilies. This way QGIS can often use also the misconfigured WMS servers.